# XML namespaces (beginner level)

Tags: xml

The question I want to ask is about XML namespaces. Pretty much everytime I see a namespace declaration, it's pointing to some website somewhere.

But here's what I don't get. In my XML has a namespace which points to www.x.com/y, does this mean that some part of the application looks up this URL and gets some document which specifies what tags are within that namespace? If yes, what would happen if I tried to develop while not online? If no, is it just a unique name for the same of avoiding conflicts? If this is the case, could I just put anything there, so long as it's unique?

Thanks.

Comment: XML namespaces are just **unique names** - they often take the shape of a URL, but they **don't point to a file on a web server** or anything - it's **just a name** (like a namespace in your favorite programming language)

Comment: @marc_s I'd recommend posting your answers below rather than adding comments to the question-space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The namespaces just *look* like URLs. They don't need to point to any real document. It's just a way to identify some namespace - no internet connection needed, nothing is downloaded.

By using a URL, every company can have it's own namespaces without fear of colliding with namespaces used by some other company.

Comment: Can you show us an example where collision occurs, so that we can appreciate the need for this namespace better ?

Comment: @AppleGrinder - you could have an XML document with different types of nodes. If there are `<widget>` nodes from different companies and both use "ourwidgets" as namespace, then you still can't differentiate between them. By using a URL-like namespace you *will* have different names.

Answer (score 1):

XML namespaces are a way of making element and attribute names unique - analogous to package names in Java, say. XML namespaces can be linked to grammars/schema using the `schemaLocation` attribute, which can help to validate XML documents.